# Как спарсить значения из таблицы docx?

Tags: xml, парсер, xmlparser, docx

существует ли какой-то относительно простой способ спарсить значения таблиц, которые находятся в файле .docx?
Можно было бы распаковать docx, как архив, вытащить оттуда XML и далее уже любым XML парсером взять нужные значения, но трудность в том, что структура XML слишком нагроможденная и не понятно, как в ней ориентироваться. 
Вот пример XML взятый из вордовского document.xml.

```
<w:t>2,95</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="683" w:type="dxa" />
<w:tcBorders><w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
<w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
<w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
<w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
</w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="P1" />
<w:widowControl w:val="0" />
<w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="240" w:after="0" />
<w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="C3" />
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Segoe UI" w:hAnsi="Segoe UI" />
<w:sz w:val="18" />
</w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="C3" />
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Tahoma" w:hAnsi="Tahoma" />
<w:sz w:val="18" />
</w:rPr><w:t>11,5</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="667" w:type="dxa" />
<w:tcBorders><w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
<w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
<w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
<w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:shadow="0" w:frame="0" w:color="000000" />
</w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="P1" />
<w:widowControl w:val="0" />
<w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="240" w:after="0" />
<w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="C3" />
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Segoe UI" w:hAnsi="Segoe UI" />
<w:sz w:val="18" />
</w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="C3" />
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Tahoma" w:hAnsi="Tahoma" />
<w:sz w:val="18" />
</w:rPr>
```

Comment: А какой язык программирования?

Comment: Формат docx действительно весьма сложный. Поэтому лучше взять готовую библиотеку для работы с ним. Какую имено - зависит от используемого языка программирования.

Comment: Например, python